# You will have the answer

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, password

A small puzzle to pass the time, because there's nothing else to do.
Find the password from the riddle, with your reasoning.

(A note to non-native speakers and really everyone, yes this puzzle requires an English dictionary.)

Riddle:

10 is the password,
the weapon of choice;
9 tracks your progress,
and 8 the sung voice.

7 tracks your speech;
then 6 will accuse.
5's bright and 4's hollow;
3's nearly sin if I lose.

2 is in 3 and
in this riddle thrice.
1 is the solver,
a char will suffice.

Hint:

> This puzzle is not quite what it seems. Although it is possible to use the riddle to find the answer, if it were missing you would still have the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> **DICTIONARY**

Because the lines of this riddle represent:

> definitions of words that can be made by removing 1 letter at a time, starting with **DICTIONARY** and ending with **I**. The numbers in each line indicate the word length.

*10 is the password,*
*the weapon of choice;*

> DICTIONARY - The puzzle tells us that we *require an English dictionary*. The 10-letter word 'dictionary' is both our *password* and our *weapon of choice* for this puzzle, then...

*9 tracks your progress,*

> INDICATOR - This part of a car displays to other drivers which way you are about to turn (i.e. *tracks your progress*).

*and 8 the sung voice.*

> [DIATONIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatonic_scale) - A scale in music.

*7 tracks your speech;*
*then 6 will accuse.*

> [DICTION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diction) and [INDICT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indict).

*5's bright and 4's hollow;*

> [NITID](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nitid) (bright and glossy) and [DINT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dint) (a dent or a hollow).

*3's nearly sin if I lose.*
*2 is in 3 and*
*in this riddle thrice.*

> 3 is either DIN or TIN. If 'if I lose' represents 'shifting a character down by 1' then TIN would become 'SIN' and fits best, but there's an argument for interpreting it in the context of a QWERTY computer keyboard, in which case moving 1 along from S gives you D, hence DIN...
>
>  Either way, 2 is IN - it's found within 3 and also in the riddle three times, twice by itself and once within 'sin'.

*1 is the solver,*
*a char will suffice.*

> Remove the 'N' and **I** am the solver! 'A char will suffice' here, since the 'char' data type in various programming languages stores a single byte of memory, enough for *a single character* - in our case, the letter 'I'.

Comment: Excellent work! I was thinking Sn for tin ( lost I) but your explanation is just as good.